# How to mask my landing page when user not signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, web

I got my web platform built on ruby on rails at https://example.com

My landing and about pages are hosted in a Wordpress in other host at https://examplecms.com.

What i would like to achieve is to make users to visit https://example.com get masked https://examplecms.com except when they are logged in as my platform's dashboard is routed in the root path /.

What i am trying to avoid is the user to see in the URL https://examplecms.com.

I've tried so far a couple of tricks:

- In my home/index action controller i've redirected to https://examplecms.com if the user is not signed in. But this fails as it still shows the CMS url in the user's browser.
- Using an Iframe in the render of the home/index view pointing to the CMS site. It works because it stills present my site URL correctly but this seems kind of fishy also deep linking and navigating does not seem to work correctly.

I have been thinking into doing at proxy server level, using .htaccess or even using DNS strategies but i can't come up for a solution to these strategies to detect when the user is signed in or not?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Update:
Stack:

- Ubuntu
- Ruby on Rails
- Nginx + passenger
- Amazon Ec2 + Cloudflare DNS

Comment: If you are using `nginx` it has an option for internal redirects - https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/ 
I have not used it for this specific use case. Will try to see if I can recreate what you like but you should give it a shot if you have a setup ready

Comment: Another crude way of doing it would be to load `examplecms` via javascript/jquery after your server responds with the auth information. Something like `$("body").load(" https://examplecms.com");`

Comment: Have you tried https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request ? It should be simple if you can expose a endpoint to nginx to check auth and then you can redirect the client based on the same

Comment: Did any answers answer your question? If yes, please be kind enough to accept and/or award the bounty.  If you perform no action within 16 hours of the grace period, at least half the bounty amount will be lost irrevocably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass to silently redirect the user to a different page, without changing the URL that's shown to the user within the `Location` field of the browser.

To check whether the user is logged in, you can install an error handler via http://nginx.org/r/error_page to redirect the user only if your normal page returns an error (e.g., if the normal `proxy_pass` results in a `403 Forbidden` response, then redirect the user's request to the alternative `proxy_pass` upstream as per the error handler).

Comment: I see what you say. Do you think that with some regex that indicates that i am in the home path (/) it should display my other site URL.

Comment: But this covers only half part of it. If the user is signed in and he requests / then it will display the proxy passed site, how to tell the proxy pass directive to be ignored if signed in? Maybe i did not understand the error handler part

Comment: Well, this really should be solved in the backend on the application side; it's just that it's also possible to solve it within nginx, hence my answer due to you tagging the Q w/ nginx tag. :)  For the error handling, the expectation is that the backend would return `403` error code only when the user is not authenticated, which will cause the `error_page` to become activated (e.g., `error_page =403 @nonauth;`), which would then do an unrelated `proxy_pass` that will hide the real URL (`location @nonauth {proxy_pass http://...;}`).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is route scopes. I'm using Devise for authentication, which provides helpers for doing what you want, but I have no doubt you can adjust for your needs. When a user hits any page on the site, they are automatically redirected to the login. If they are logged in, they are redirected to the homepage/URL they typed in.

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: 'titles#index'
end

devise_scope :user do
  root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Comment: This wont work because i need to mask a different url inside the url of my site, so routing does not covers this

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a subdomain

For your WordPress hosted web content, you could create a very simple subdomain on your hosting provider like so
`blog.example.com` that is alias to examplecms.com

#### Use Device Gem for Authentication

You can use the device gem to authenticate the user and route the user to the subdomain. When the user hits the /root_path.

Comment: Yeah this works but won't feed the requirements described